# apache2 keeps crashing 1- 3 times a day

Tags: linux, debian, apache2.4

i'm running a debian server with apache 2.4, and php 7.*
1 - 3 times a day my website goes down and i have to restart apache to get it up again.

i'm rather new to linux so i dont realy know how to debug apache :/

any advise is strongly appriciated!

Server stats:

ram: 32 Gb ram

hd: 2x 256Gb ssh 600/600Mb

2 cpu with 6 cores i dont remember the stats of the cpus

apache status before crash:

```
 ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-05-12 16:31:45 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 1540 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27533 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1566 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─1581 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1584 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1585 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1586 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1587 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─1588 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

May 12 16:31:45 something.com apache2[1566]: Starting web server: apac...
May 12 16:31:45 something.com systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web se....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

apache status after crash:

```
   apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-05-11 13:06:04 CEST; 1 day 3h ago
  Process: 16209 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27533 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16234 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─16249 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16268 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16290 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16299 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16382 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16385 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16388 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16437 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16513 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16660 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16930 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16934 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16946 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16976 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16983 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16989 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16991 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17171 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17190 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17270 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17319 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17320 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17377 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17383 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17387 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17407 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17412 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17722 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17750 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17753 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17756 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17757 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17836 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17858 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17873 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17883 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17885 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17937 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17938 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17945 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17949 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─17953 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18006 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18015 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18080 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18092 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18097 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18154 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18223 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18224 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18226 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18239 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18342 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18347 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18348 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18353 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18364 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18399 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18403 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18404 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18419 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18451 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18526 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18531 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18583 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18603 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18628 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18647 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18697 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18699 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18706 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18714 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18731 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18732 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18736 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18737 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18754 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18791 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18804 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18811 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18812 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18818 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18819 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18822 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18832 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18844 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18845 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18846 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18852 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18856 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18919 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18927 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18934 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18940 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18956 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18962 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18967 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18968 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18973 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18977 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─18983 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19022 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19076 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19083 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19095 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19096 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19107 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19114 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19116 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19125 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19126 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19128 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19130 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19131 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19139 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19141 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19143 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19154 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19158 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19161 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19166 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19167 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19168 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19169 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19171 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19203 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19204 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19220 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19222 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19223 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19225 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19226 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19227 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19228 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19232 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19235 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19236 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19237 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19238 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19241 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19243 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19249 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19252 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19253 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19255 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19256 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19268 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19270 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19276 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─19281 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─19285 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

May 11 13:06:04 something.com apache2[16234]: Starting web server: apa...
May 11 13:06:04 something.com systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web se....
May 12 06:52:37 something.com systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web ....
May 12 06:52:38 something.com apache2[27533]: Reloading web server: ap...
May 12 06:52:38 something.com systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Apache2 web s....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

apache2 error log:

```
   [Thu May 12 06:52:38.198334 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 16249] AH01906: something.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu May 12 06:52:38.198457 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16249] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 12 06:52:38.198462 2016] [core:notice] [pid 16249] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu May 12 16:31:43.877771 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16249] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu May 12 16:31:44.905366 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1580] AH01906: something.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu May 12 16:31:44.925525 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1581] AH01906: something.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu May 12 16:31:44.926946 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1581] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 12 16:31:44.926959 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1581] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName  something.com
        ServerAlias www.something.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/public_html/

         <Directory /var/www/sitename/public_html/>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Options indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Logfiles
     ErrorLog /home/Glausten/website/sitename/logs/sitename_error_logs.log
     CustomLog /home/Glausten/website/sitename/logs/sitename_access_logs.log common
</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#        ServerName something.com
#        DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/public_html/
#
#</VirtualHost>
#
#
#<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
#<VirtualHost *:443>
#
#        ServerAdmin something@gmail.com
#        ServerName something.com
#        DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/public_html/
#
        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
#        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
#        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
#        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
#</VirtualHost>

#</IfModule>
```

Is there anything else i can post to help locate the problem?

====================!=!=!=====================

i just might have located the problem

noticed a new error in the error log saying :

```
server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

then i started googleing and wounded up on this site:

http://cloudinservice.com/tune-apache-performance-using-mpm-prefork-module/
that gave me some insigt in whats happening in the mpm-prefork-module

then i noticed that `MaxConnectionsPerChild` where set to 0 meaning if i have some php scripts with a little memory leak that wil continue to grow and eat up more off the memory without releasing any over time which explains why the server suddenly goes down i've modified the file according to my resources and restarted apache.

i'll see how it goes for the next few days and if it dossent crash i'll return and post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that you have to configure apache depending on your server configuration.
I had same problem with digital ocean and his tiny droplet.
The best way is to limit concurent connections. But if you can provide more info about logs, machine configuration you should get a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so depending on your hardware configuration it could be because you use a tiny server. Digital ocean suggest to create for tiny machine a config file for apache which allow 15 child process (by supposing apache use 10M for each child process). You can edit or create `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          3
    MinSpareServers       3
    MaxSpareServers       5
    MaxClients           30
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Taken from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance)

This configuration is good enough for an apache child process using 10 M and a server having 512M ram

Comment: its a dedicated server rented at hetzner,
32 Gb ram, 2x 256Gb ssd hb 600/600Mbs, 2 cpus with 6 cores i dont remember what they where on.... so its not a tiny server

Comment: is there anything else i could post that could lead to finding the problem?

Comment: Maybe it could help, 
*i noticed more than 150+ child apache process.
*Apache also stop to work normally (like it's seems not to be a crash)   Process: 16209 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27533 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16234 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: I would suggest you to use top, or htop and survey your process

Comment: okay i tried useing top and looked at how apache was running while the site was up and when the site wassent up and the resource usage was the same.......

Comment: watching it with top now, the ram usage for apache just raises and raises it takes about 1 Gb ram per 25 - 40 min and just keep going like that